# Sound is staticy on Squeeze

Tags: debian

I have recently setup a Debian Squeeze virtual machine, which uses OpenBox, via VirtualBox and got things work somewhat right, but I am having issues with sound.

When I launch Google Chrome, which is the only browser I have in the VM, and go to YouTube, in order to test the sound via a video, everything sounds staticy. How do I get rid of the static?

This is what the machine reports to be the sound card

> 00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97
>   Audio Controller (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Virtualbox guest additions?

[Guest Additions Install](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15679)

Comment: the guest additions were installed during either the OS install process or install software through apt-get, I believe, at least the ose version. I could try out the ones offered via the menubar.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue. You need to disable the flash plugin that ships with Chrome, called PepperFlash, by typing `about:plugins` into the omnibar and finding the PepperFlash plugin then clicking on `Disable`.
To replace PepperFlash with something that works, you should add the `non-free` branch to your repos by appending `non-free` after the relevant line(s) in `/etc/apt/sources.list` then running

```
apt-get update
apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

which will install Adobe's proprietary flash plugin.

---

**Edit**

As far as I know this has nothing to do with VirtualBox. I ran into this issue on a native system.